# How to set Context in tests without custom interceptors

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I try to write unit tests like shown in [RouteGuideServerTest.java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/routeguide/RouteGuideServerTest.java). The fact is that my service reads some user context info (like userID, ip and etc.) from `Context.Key<UserContext>` which is set in some `UserContextInterceptor`.
The problem is that I don't want to same create interceptor in JUnit testing code and want to set Context manually right in the test method but cannot find the way to make it properly.

I have some `Context.Key<UserContext> USER_CONTEXT` in `Constant.java` and tried to set Context the next way:

```
Context.current().withValue(Constant.USER_CONTEXT, userContext).run(() -> { // some testing code })
```

but as the *run* happens in different thread from caller thread the context returned from `Constant.USER_CONTEXT.get()` is always `null` in service code.

**Constant.java**:

```java
public static final Context.Key<UserContext> USER_CONTEXT = Context.key("userContext");
```

**GrpcService.java**

```java
@Override
    public StreamObserver<EntityRequest> process(StreamObserver<EntityResponse> responseObserver) {
        return new StreamObserver<EntityRequest>() {

            @Override
            public void onNext(EntityRequest request) {
                Constant.USER_CONTEXT.get(); // is always null in tests
            }
            // other methods
        };
}
```

**GrpcServiceTest.java**

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    UserContext mockedContext = ...; // set user context 
    Context.current().withValue(Constant.USER_CONTEXT, mockedContext)
        .run(() -> {
            // testing code, call service rpc method  
        });
}
```

What is the proper way to set Context in tests without interceptors to use it their mocked values in `GrpcService` without nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to which thread is used for execution. `Context.run()` runs within the current thread. And `RouteGuideServerTest` already uses `serverBuilder.directExecutor()` to have the service run within the test thread.

The problem is that the server has its own root `Context` it uses for inbound RPCs, separate from whatever `Context` happens to be on the current thread when being called. That requires an interceptor to change.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much. Could you tell me if setting the context during the service call is the only possible solution to retrieve request scope parameters? Maybe there is some best practice or mechanism exists in gRPC World, I've found only context examples.

Comment: Context is our official recommendation. Is there an issue with Context/interceptor that is causing you problems? What is wrong with an interceptor?